# SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo for ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax returns null

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to get symbol info from `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax` object but failed.

Here is example that reproduce the problem:

```
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
{
    foreach (var kvp in _hm.Where(x => x.Key.IsAlive))
    {
        yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(kvp.Key.Target, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

get "`new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(kvp.Key.Target, kvp.Value)`" symbol failed
but using Roslyn Syntax Visualizer can get it.

I write a method, eg.

```
public static T GetRawSymbol<T>(SemanticModel semanticModel, SyntaxNode syntax) where T : class, ISymbol
    {
        var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(syntax).Symbol;
        if (symbol == null)
            symbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(syntax);
        if (symbol == null)
        {
            symbol = semanticModel.GetPreprocessingSymbolInfo(syntax).Symbol;
        }
        if (symbol == null)
            return symbol as T;
        else
            return symbol.OriginalDefinition as T;
    }
```

`GetSymbolInfo, GetDeclaredSymbol, GetPreprocessingSymbolInfo` are all return null

Comment: Per https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3825 `GetDeclaredSymbol` should return null in this case, while `GetSymbolInfo` returning null seems to be a bug. `GetPreprocessingSymbolInfo` might have its own story.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax` itself doesn't have a symbol.  You need to get the the symbol from its `Type` property, which returns the syntax node for the type after the `new` keyword.

Comment: So there is no way to get the symbol of the invoked constructor?

Comment: But I can't get symbol only this,other ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax I can get symbol,eg. A a=new A(); this symbol is not null,can you tell me why some can and the other not?

Comment: Type property's symbol is the invoked constructor's class symbol not constructor's symbol